# How to remove Admin from Request url in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using below code to form url :

```
PricingLink = Url.Action("PricingRequestSummary", "GlobalPricing", new { id = pricingId }, this.Request.Url.Scheme)
```

Gives me result as :

http://localhost:56287/Admin/GlobalPricing/PricingRequestSummary/4

I want only (Admin i dont want)

http://localhost:56287/GlobalPricing/PricingRequestSummary/4

How to achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: Add .Replace("Admin", null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are executing the `Url.Action` helper method from a view under the `Admin` area. By default it will use the current area name when building the urls. But you can override this by explicitly passing an empty string as area name.

```
<a href="Url.Action("PricingRequestSummary", "GlobalPricing", 
         new { id = pricingId, area = string.Empty }, this.Request.Url.Scheme)">Test</a>
```